# Ethernet connection RX lost with LWIP

Tags: c, embedded, ethernet, dhcp, lwip

I have a ethernet connection with LWIP library and I am sending snmp trap periodically. I have no problem about sending snmp trap but the program started and after a while, my device can not answer any request on ethernet (ping or snmp get, set etc.) But it can still send snmp trap. My main loop is here. Additionly, if I use DHCP, there is no problem about pinging, but If I use static ip the program works just 10-20 minutes and after it can not take a ping.

```
    while(FOREVER){
        if (netif_is_link_up(&gnetif))
        {
            /* When the netif is fully configured this function must be called */
            netif_set_up(&gnetif); 
        }
        else
        {
            /* When the netif link is down this function must be called */
            netif_set_down(&gnetif);
        }
}
```

Comment: sounds like you are using a resource and not freeing it.  Network buffers, maybe?

Comment: Thank you! The problem about hardware. Eeprom have some problems. I exchange it and solved.